# Nativescript ios - Command xcodebuild failed with exit code null

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, nativescript, tns

I have setup a new nativescript app by running the following:-

```
tns create application --ng
```

When I attempt to launch the application using:-

```
tns run ios --emulator
```

I get the following error:-

```
Unable to apply changes on device: BC7714A3-A8B0-4CEC-A7A4-D54563CF04EE. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code null.
```

The full error is:-

```
Searching for devices...
Executing before-liveSync hook from /XXXXXX/Desktop/Bike/hooks/before-liveSync/nativescript-angular-sync.js
Skipping prepare.
Building project...
Xcode build...
2018-04-30 21:49:36.684 xcodebuild[1674:27197] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-13756/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/RuntimeSupport/MacroExpansion/XCMacroExpansionExtensions.mm:94
Details:  Assertion failed: [value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
Object:   <DVTMacroDefinitionTable: 0x7fab68c72bb0>
Method:   -_xc_setValue:forMacroName:conditionSet:errorHandler:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fab68d176a0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4   -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) _xc_setValue:forMacroName:conditionSet:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5   -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) _xc_setValue:forMacroName:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6   __108-[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) xc_setMacroNamesAndValuesFromDictionary:errorHandler:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
  7   -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation)
  8   -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) xc_setMacroNamesAndValuesFromDictionary:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9   +[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCProjectArchivingExtensions) xc_macroDefinitionTableFromDictionaryRepresentationForProjectArchiving:usingPropertyDefinitionsFromSpecificationDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10   -[PBXBuildStyle _setBuildSettings:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11   -[PBXUnarchivingBinding readValueForObject:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12   -[PBXObject _unarchiveValuesForArchiveMask:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13   -[PBXObject readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14   -[PBXBuildStyle readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 15   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _unarchiveObjectWithGlobalIDHexString:] (in DevToolsCore)
 16   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _decodeMutableObjectArrayFromPListArray:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeMutableObjectArrayForKey:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18   -[PBXUnarchivingBinding readValueForObject:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 19   -[PBXObject _unarchiveValuesForArchiveMask:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 20   -[PBXObject readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 21   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _unarchiveObjectWithGlobalIDHexString:] (in DevToolsCore)
 22   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:] (in DevToolsCore)
 23   -[PBXUnarchivingBinding readValueForObject:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 24   -[PBXObject _unarchiveValuesForArchiveMask:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 25   -[PBXObject readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 26   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _unarchiveObjectWithGlobalIDHexString:] (in DevToolsCore)
 27   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _decodeMutableObjectArrayFromPListArray:] (in DevToolsCore)
 28   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeMutableObjectArrayForKey:] (in DevToolsCore)
 29   -[PBXUnarchivingBinding readValueForObject:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 30   -[PBXObject _unarchiveValuesForArchiveMask:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 31   -[PBXObject readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 32   -[PBXProject readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 33   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _unarchiveObjectWithGlobalIDHexString:] (in DevToolsCore)
 34   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeRootObject] (in DevToolsCore)
 35   +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
 36   -[Xcode3Project initWithFilePath:extension:workspace:options:error:] (in DevToolsCore)
 37   __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
 38   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 39   _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
 40   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
 41   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 42   __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 43   __58-[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 44   -[DVTModelGraphTransactionScope performTransaction:] (in DVTFoundation)
 45   -[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:] (in DVTFoundation)
 46   +[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 47   +[IDEContainer retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 48   -[IDEWorkspace _configureWrappedWorkspaceWithError:] (in IDEFoundation)
 49   -[IDEWorkspace _setContainerFilePath:upgradeToWorkspace:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 50   +[IDEContainer retainedWrappedWorkspaceForContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 51   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _resolveInputOptionsWithTimingSection:] (in Xcode3Core)
 52   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
 53  0x00000001007592af (in xcodebuild)
 54   start (in libdyld.dylib)
Unable to apply changes on device: BC7714A3-A8B0-4CEC-A7A4-D54563CF04EE. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code null.
Executing after-watch hook from /XXXXXX/Desktop/Bike/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
```

The application occasionally launches without an issue, but stops 95% of the time I get the error above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If anybody else is having this issue you need to run:-

```
tns platform remove ios; tns platform add ios
```

in your terminal and this will fix the issue.

Comment: This is strange, i've faced many issues in order to run this damn ios simulator finally.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command 
rm -rf node_modules/ hooks/ platforms/

And then yarn install/npm install and then run project.This will fix the issue.